# change view error

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller

Hi
when I switch from one view to another, I do:

```
-(void)goInGame {

InGameViewController = [[InGameView alloc] initWithNibName:@"InGameView" bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:self.InGameViewController animated:NO];
[InGameViewController release];

}
```

However, in this way retain count of InGameViewController is "0", but the retain count of InGameView is "-1", and sometimes crashes

error:
Terminating app to two Uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load bundle NIB:' NSBundle <.... app> (loaded) 'with name ' InGameView''

where am I wrong?

thanks!

Comment: There seems to be some problem with the NIB file. Have you checked that? And is `InGameViewController` a `retain`-ed property?

Comment: Do not call **retainCount**.  It is useless.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you want to explicitly release your controller. Try removing the line `[InGameViewController release];` and see if that fixes your problem.

For more information, check out Apple's [Memory Management Rules](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html) as well as [Behind the Scenes: Retain Counts](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmObjectOwnership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000043-SW2) in the [Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000011-SW1), which states that

> If an object’s retain count is reduced
>   to 0, it is deallocated (see
>   “Deallocating an Object”).

Furthermore,

> Important: Typically there should be
>   no reason to explicitly ask an object
>   what its retain count is (see
>   retainCount). The result is often
>   misleading, as you may be unaware of
>   what framework objects have retained
>   an object in which you are interested.
>   In debugging memory management issues,
>   you should be concerned only with
>   ensuring that your code adheres to the
>   ownership rules.

Your application crashes because it is trying to access your view controller, which has already been deallocated.

Comment: removing that line the retain count of inGameView (not GameViewController) is always -1

Comment: @Vins Just out of curiosity, why are you assigning an initialized instance of `InGameView` to `InGameViewController`? Are they both the same class?

Comment: it is the same class, is the only way I know to switch from one to another uiviewcontroller. You think I'm wrong?

Comment: @Vins I don't see any variable named `inGameView` in your code. `InGameView`, on the other hand, is the name of a class.

Comment: As Chris said, your memory management is wrong;  you shouldn't be releasing `InGameController` (which should be `inGameController`, btw).  That hte NIB doesn't load appears to potentially be unrelated.  Do you have an `InGameView` class in your app?  Yah -- what Chris said.  I'd bet that you renamed an instance variable and din't fix the connection in the NIB file.

Comment: yes sorry, InGameView is name of class and inGameViewController is the name of instance